# It's been a month since I didn't hear back about a technical evaluation which I was selected for; what do I do?

Tags: internship, india, follow-up

On February 2nd, I got a Google form in my inbox which required me to fill in details such as internship field preference, duration and start date. The last date for filling this form was February 8th. I filled the form on time, but haven't heard back about the technical evaluation which was to be conducted for selecting interns. I don't have any contact with the HR team of this company and all my attempts to connect with the HR people of this company on LinkedIn have failed.

My last vacation (since I'm in the final year of my engineering program) has started on March 1st, and I'm feeling anxious.

I got this email to fill the form from the coordinator of the university program of the company. I've contacted the coordinator on both email and phone but she said she has given the rank list to the HR Team and she can't do anything else, since it is all left to the HR team. I had followed up with her on 2nd March and she said HR team said they are in the process.

We were shortlisted to fill this form and take the technical evaluation based on our performance in online courses and tests sponsored and conducted by this company in December 2020.

I've also tried contacting engineers at this company but they can't help me either. I'm now **thinking of creating a post on LinkedIn and tagging this company, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea**. Has anyone been in this situation and could give some guidelines for creating such a post?

This company does not visit the college which I attend for campus recruitment and they have recently hired students for internships from other colleges.

I don't want to miss this opportunity since I've invested money to write the online test and a lot of time and effort to prepare for it along with my college work.

This company is a large, multinational American semiconductor company. I'm open to considering other options to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> It's been a month since I didn't hear back about a technical
> evaluation which I was selected for, what do I do?

Unfortunately for you, it sounds like you have done what you can and will have to wait. Also, *consider the possibility* that they have moved on from you as well.  At this point, consider this as "iron still in the fire", and pursue **other internship opportunities**.

> I've also tried contacting engineers at this company but they can't
> help me either. I'm now thinking of creating a post on LinkedIn and
> tagging this company, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea. Has
> anyone been in this situation and could give some guidelines for
> creating such a post?

I would not recommend reaching out to other employees of the company. They may not even know about the opportunity you're looking into or where to direct you.  (*Not much to gain here, and this may be a tad on the desperate side.*)

And, unless you want to risk getting potentially blacklisted by the company you're interested in, definitely don't contact them on LinkedIn via a tag / post.  This falls into the desperate / borderline annoying category from the company's perspective.

Answer (score 5):

A month is nothing if there are a lot of candidates.

You really need to let the process work its way through.

Do not contact the company directly, and stop harassing its employees on LinkedIn.

If there are a lot of candidates, they will be looking for ways of filtering out the list. They will see your behaviour, find your application in the stack of applications, and throw it in the bin.

They can also report you for harassment to LinkedIn. And LinkedIn does do **shadow banning** based on heuristics too. If a whole bunch of employees block you, LinkedIn will start filtering your messages. You don't want that hanging over your head when you're trying to secure an internship.

Instead, you should be spending you time filling applications for other internships, rather than putting all your eggs into one basket.

Comment: Isn't harassing too harsh a term for what I did? I agree with this answer though.

Comment: It may be too harsh. Or it may be fitting. I don't know. But any repeated attempt at communicating employees of an organisation could be viewed as harassment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.